# AsyncCassandraOperations examples

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data

I am reading up on AsyncCassandraOperations to perform async inserts to improve performance based on another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707275/slow-insert-and-saveall-performance-on-spring-data-cassandra-repository). But I am unable to find a lot of help on google or spring data documentation.

Previously I was using Cassandra Repository for all data extraction and insert/updates which I found to be super slow. As per recommendation I am now using AsyncCassandraOperations for the insert operation alone, but it wont let me. I encounter *required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.AsyncCassandraOperations'* error.

What would be the correct way to use AsyncCassandraOperations please?

```
@Autowired private MyRepository repository_name;
@Autowired private AsyncCassandraOperations acops;
public void persist(List<POJO> l_POJO)
{
        System.out.println("Enter Persist: "+new java.util.Date());

        List<l_POJO> l_POJO_stale = repository_name.findBycol1AndStale("sample",false);

        l_POJO_stale.forEach(s -> s.setStale(true));

        l_POJO_stale.forEach(s -> acops.update(s));

        try 
        {
            acops.insert(l_POJO);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error in persisting new data");
        }
}
```

Comment: please provide the version information of spring data you are using. and for your reference, there is an reactive cassandra example here:https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/cassandra/reactive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know whether spring boot is used, if so the AsyncCassandraOperations(AsyncCassandraTemplate is the implementation class) should be created automatically.
If the error shows you need an AsyncCassandraOperations bean, the straight way is to create one as shown below.

```java
@Bean
AsyncCassandraTemplate asyncCassandraTemplate(Session session) {
    return new AsyncCassandraTemplate(session);
}
```

Since you are using Spring data Repository interface, you can alse use the `ReactiveCrudRepository` interface to update or insert entity objects to Cassandra, which is shown in [this spring data example project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/cassandra/reactive) ,  as an alternative way to using the `AsyncCassandraTemplate` class.

In the case of using `ReactiveCrudRepository` and regarding what you want to do, your code needs the following changes.

1. change the return type of `WRRepository.findByCol1AndCol2AndCol3(String, boolean, String)` from `List<WRpojo>` to `Flux<WRpojo>` , in order to fully utilize the reactive functionality.
2. change the return type of `persist(List<WRpojo>)` from boolean to `Mono<Void>` , making the result non-blocking too.
3. change your `persist(List<WRpojo>)` to the following.

```java
  public Mono<Void> persist(List<WRpojo> l_wr) {
    Flux<WRpojo> l_old_wr = objWRRepository.findByCol1AndCol2AndCol3("1", false, "2").doOnNext(s -> s.setStale(true));
    return objWRRepository.saveAll(l_old_wr).thenMany(objWRRepository.saveAll(l_wr)).then();
  }
```

In reactive programming, basically we don't block any code, this means that somewhere the returned `Mono<Void>` should be subscribed somewhere downstream, if you do want to block and wait for all operations complete, you can call `block()` on `Mono<Void>` , which is not recommended.

Comment: I 've still not managed to figure this out. I am trying to save a list of objects using ReactiveCrudRepository in the below manner. But it does not seem to work for me 
Basically what I am trying to do is save a list of objects onto cassandra. But before I save it, I need to extract another set of objects, mark it as stale, persist it and then continue persisting the new list of objects.

Comment: `@Repository
public interface WRRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<WRpojo, String>
{
 @Query(allowFiltering = true)
 List<WRpojo> findByCol1AndCol2AndCol3(final String col1,final boolean col2, final String col3);
}                                                                                                                                      `

Comment: `@Service                                                                                                                              public boolean persist(List<WRpojo> l_wr)
{
 List<WRpojo> l_old_wr = objWRRepository.findByCol1AndCol2AndCol3("1",false,"2");
 l_old_wr.forEach(s -> s.setStale(true));
 //the above forEach command fails with error reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly cannot be cast to
 objWRRepository.saveAll(l_old_wr);
 objWRRepository.saveAll(l_wr);
}`