# saveAll() is too slow. Cassandra Database with Spring boot. why?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra

I am trying to insert in batches (Objects are stored in an arraylist and as soon as count is divisible by 10000, I insert all these objects into my table. But it takes more than 4 minutes to do so. Is there any approach which is faster?

```
arr.add(new Car(name, count, type));
if(count%10000==0){
repository.saveAll(arr);
arr.clear();
}
```

Comment: Did you look at what Spring JPA is doing?

Comment: No, @NoDataFound.. I'm still learning.. sorry if this is a dumb question!

Comment: Try reducing `10000` limit and see if that helps?

Comment: Not related to performance. But if you want batch inserts set this property  -  
`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=10000`. Simply use `repository.saveall(arr)`

Comment: Which driver are you using?  Is this Spring Data Cassandra?

Comment: Check the system.log file on one of your Cassandra nodes.  Are you getting any warnings or exceptions?

Comment: @aaron no warnings.. it's just really slow..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here is what is happening.  I am most curious to see the table definition inside Cassandra.  But given your `Car` constructor,

```
new Car(name, count, type)
```

Given those column names, I'm guessing that `name` is the partition key.

The reason that is significant, is because the *hash* of the partition key column is what Cassandra uses to figure out which node (token range) the data should be written to.

When you `saveAll` on 10000 `Cars` at once, there is *no way* you can guarantee that all 10000 of those are going to the same node.  To deal with this, Spring Data Cassandra must be using a `BATCH` (or something like it) behind the scenes.  If it is a `BATCH`, that essentially puts one Cassandra node (designated as a "coordinator") to route writes to the required nodes.  Due to Cassandra's distributed nature, **that is never going to be fast.**

If you really need to store 10000 of them, the best way would be send one write at a time *asynchronously*.  Of course, you won't want 10000 threads all writing concurrently, so you'll want to throttle-down (limit) the number of active threads in your code.  DataStax's Ryan Svihla has written a couple of articles detailing how to do this.  I recommend this one- [Cassandra: Batch Loading Without the Batch - The Nuanced Edition](https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-the-nuanced-edition-dd78d61e9885).

**tl;dr;**

Spring Data Cassandra's `saveAll` really shouldn't be used to persist several thousand writes.  If I were using Spring Data Cassandra, I wouldn't even go beyond double-digits with `saveAll`, TBH.

**Edit**

Check out this answer for details on how to use Spring Boot/Data with Cassandra asyncrhonously: [AsyncCassandraOperations examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711538/asynccassandraoperations-examples)

Comment: Yes @Aaron! Name is the partition key  and count is the clustering key.. and one thing to note.. I only try to store data belonging to one partition at a time..

Comment: can you suggest something for the spring boot version?? Something similar.. I'm new to this and the blog is a little confusing.. do u suggest keeping the batch size to double digits.. anything else that I can do? Thank you so much :)

Comment: @nar-007 Edit made.